# Nest loop with two while loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

So I have to come up with a code that outputs a report, and I have to enclose this while loop within another while loop, one that will ask the user if he wants to continue inputting info. As long as the user responds "Y", continue asking for required inputs and print the report. Once the user answers "N", then stop further processing.

I just finished the loop that generates the report, but I don't know how to enclose this loop with another loop with the above requirement.

My current code for the report is like this:

```
while (bookVal > salvageVal){
    //read in stuff

    yearlyDepr = bookVal * (ddRate / 100);
    accDepr = accDepr + yearlyDepr;
    bookVal = bookVal - yearlyDepr;
    year++;

    if (bookVal < salvageVal){
        yearlyDepr = (bookVal + yearlyDepr) - salvageVal;
        accDepr = purchPrice - salvageVal;
        bookVal = salvageVal;

    }
    System.out.printf("%d %,18.0f %,18.0f %,18.0f%n" , year, yearlyDepr, accDepr, bookVal);
}
```

I tried putting a "read in for Y or N" at the end of this loop and set another while loop on top of it with something like: while (answer == 'Y'), but that just scews up everything...Some help would be nice, thanks!

Comment: try coding it first, then show us where you are stuck

Comment: Wrapping a second loop around this one will do what you want it to. If it does not, then that indicates you did something wrong. Show us your attempt at the second loop, and explain what "that screws up everything" means.

Comment: In addition to the words describing what you tried, you should show the actual code that you described as well.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Looks like the OP is comparing to `'Y'` not `"Y"`, so maybe not a dupe

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ahh...too much Python and JavaScript lately where those are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String toContinue="y";
while( (your code) && "y".equalsIgnoreCase(toContinue))
{
      //your code
      System.out.println("Do you want to continue : (Y-to continue,any otherto stop )");
      toContinue=s.next();
}
```

Comment: This does not compile since `'y'` cannot be assigned to `String toContinue`

Comment: `String toContinue="y"; `

Comment: Thanks this helped, although I did not use the part with the: while((your code) &&. I did not get what thats suppose to do.